# Do Cisco "Small Business" products come with support, or do you need to pay for a Cisco service contract?

Tags: cisco

I recently bought a Cisco RV110W Small Business wireless vpn firewall and I want to open a support case with the Cisco TAC.  I assumed small business products came with a support period but I can't determine how to open a support case without a contract.

Comment: Have you tried calling Cisco?

Comment: This was edited into HopelessN00b's answer by an anonymous user:  `The Small Business Support Center is a separate unit from "TAC". We handle the Small Business Product line and TAC handles the Enterprise line of products. If you have a small business product, you can call 1-866-606-1866 and an answering agent can help you.

- Eric Moyers Cisco Network Advanced Support Engineer SBSC Wireless and Surveillance SME`

Comment: Support is available for Cisco Small Business items, but it's really poor.  Here's a hint.  Don't buy Cisco Small Business.  Fork out the extra for the real deal.. Otherwise it's really just Linksys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define "support."  ["TAC" is not included](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/warranty_qa_guest.html), but they mention something about [small business phone support](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/warranty_qa_guest.html#%7Esmall_business), which presumably would not require a support contract.

> Q. How will the Cisco Small Business Support Center help me?
>
> A. Technical support by telephone for Cisco Small Business products will be provided for the first 12 months following the date of purchase by the original end-user purchaser (for most Cisco Small Business products purchased before September 22, 2010 and for all Cisco Small Business products purchased after September 22, 2010). One of our professional technicians will work to resolve your issue and help get your Cisco Small Business product up and running.
>
> During the product warranty period, the Cisco technician will determine whether the difficulty is the result of the Cisco Small Business product and whether your product contains a defect. If the resolution to your problem requires a hardware replacement, the Cisco technician will create a return materials authorization (RMA) for the warranty return process. This number will enable you to return your merchandise to Cisco for a replacement product.

Does kinda sound like they might tell you to RMA the device, or it's not a hardware defect, so purchase support or piss off.  Do feel free to give them a call and find out... I'd be curious to know just what they consider small business support, myself.

Comment: I define support as technical support, which would include how-tos, problems and warranty issues.  My experience with large enterprise support is great.